# How to create vertical tablix in sql server reporting services?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

Hi to all i will try to tell you what i tried to do with an example. I have table as shown below;

---

### #|a |b |c |

### 1|x1|y1|z1|

### 2|x2|y2|z2|

### 3|x3|y3|z3|

I want to create dynamic tablix for each row like below;

---

### a|x1|

### b|y1|

### c|z1|

---

### a|x2|

### b|y2|

### c|z2|

.
.
.
.
nth tablix.

I defined a dataset for a tablix. i defined the column names as row names(in the example they are a, b, c). and i can get the cell values by defining an expression like `=First(Fields!x1.Value, "dsDetails")`  for each row. But i can not figure out how to generate dynamic tablix for remaining rows. I need suggestion to continue.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to [so]! This is not a coding service! Please share an [mcve]!

Answer (score 0):

For others searching this kind of issue, there is a solution.You can create a tablix with two columns. First column will have the label you want to report and second column will have the information. The information can be displayed by inserting placeholders. An example table have been inserted below.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0z2sL.png)

If you inserted the table into a list. The report will be displayed for each row number.

PS: I fould this information on the internet. Therefore credits will go the the related person. This is just for the answer to be viewed here.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use *List* control with *Rectangle* inside placing all columns of your dataset as separate textboxes inside that rectangle as it's shown in this video:
[Using Lists in SSRS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bs2iHpVTuSw&list=PL7A29088C98E92D5F&index=16)